# add settings to Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, pthreads, plc

I have a long Makefile I created from https://github.com/libplctag/libplctag

I have my own code that I compile this way:

```
gcc -std=c11 -pthread test.c -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs libsystemd`
```

How can I add these setting to the Makefile so I can add my code to one of the c files that get compiled using this Makefile?

cmake_install.cmake file:

```
# Install script for directory: /home/tigo/libplctag

# Set the install prefix
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
endif()
string(REGEX REPLACE "/$" "" CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")

# Set the install configuration name.
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME)
  if(BUILD_TYPE)
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^[^A-Za-z0-9_]+" ""
           CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME "${BUILD_TYPE}")
  else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME "Debug")
  endif()
  message(STATUS "Install configuration: \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}\"")
endif()

# Set the component getting installed.
if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  if(COMPONENT)
    message(STATUS "Install component: \"${COMPONENT}\"")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT "${COMPONENT}")
  else()
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  endif()
endif()

# Install shared libraries without execute permission?
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE "1")
endif()

# Is this installation the result of a crosscompile?
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
  set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING "FALSE")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  if(EXISTS "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so.2.5" AND
     NOT IS_SYMLINK "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so.2.5")
    file(RPATH_CHECK
         FILE "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so.2.5"
         RPATH "")
  endif()
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY FILES "/home/tigo/libplctag/build/bin_dist/libplctag.so.2.5")
  if(EXISTS "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so.2.5" AND
     NOT IS_SYMLINK "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so.2.5")
    if(CMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP)
      execute_process(COMMAND "/usr/bin/strip" "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so.2.5")
    endif()
  endif()
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  if(EXISTS "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so" AND
     NOT IS_SYMLINK "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so")
    file(RPATH_CHECK
         FILE "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so"
         RPATH "")
  endif()
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY FILES "/home/tigo/libplctag/build/bin_dist/libplctag.so")
  if(EXISTS "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so" AND
     NOT IS_SYMLINK "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so")
    if(CMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP)
      execute_process(COMMAND "/usr/bin/strip" "$ENV{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libplctag.so")
    endif()
  endif()
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY FILES "/home/tigo/libplctag/build/bin_dist/libplctag.a")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include" TYPE FILE FILES "/home/tigo/libplctag/src/lib/libplctag.h")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xUnspecifiedx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig" TYPE FILE FILES "/home/tigo/libplctag/build/bin_dist/libplctag.pc")
endif()

if(CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST "install_manifest_${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}.txt")
else()
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST "install_manifest.txt")
endif()

string(REPLACE ";" "\n" CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_CONTENT
       "${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_FILES}")
file(WRITE "/home/tigo/libplctag/build/${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST}"
     "${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANIFEST_CONTENT}")
```

Makefile:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.16

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/tigo/libplctag

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/tigo/libplctag/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip/fast

# Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install

# Special rule for the target install
install/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Available install components are: \"Unspecified\""
.PHONY : list_install_components

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components/fast: list_install_components

.PHONY : list_install_components/fast

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/tigo/libplctag/build/CMakeFiles /home/tigo/libplctag/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/tigo/libplctag/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ab_server

# Build rule for target.
ab_server: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ab_server
.PHONY : ab_server

# fast build rule for target.
ab_server/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ab_server.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ab_server.dir/build
.PHONY : ab_server/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named write_string

# Build rule for target.
write_string: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 write_string
.PHONY : write_string

# fast build rule for target.
write_string/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/write_string.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/write_string.dir/build
.PHONY : write_string/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named thread_stress

# Build rule for target.
thread_stress: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 thread_stress
.PHONY : thread_stress

# fast build rule for target.
thread_stress/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/thread_stress.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/thread_stress.dir/build
.PHONY : thread_stress/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named cli

# Build rule for target.
cli: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 cli
.PHONY : cli

# fast build rule for target.
cli/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/cli.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cli.dir/build
.PHONY : cli/fast

# target to build an object file
src/util/vector.c.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/cli.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cli.dir/src/util/vector.c.o
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/plctag_dyn.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/plctag_dyn.dir/src/util/vector.c.o
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/plctag_static.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/plctag_static.dir/src/util/vector.c.o
.PHONY : src/util/vector.c.o

src/util/vector.i: src/util/vector.c.i

.PHONY : src/util/vector.i

# target to preprocess a source file
src/util/vector.c.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/cli.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cli.dir/src/util/vector.c.i
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/plctag_dyn.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/plctag_dyn.dir/src/util/vector.c.i
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/plctag_static.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/plctag_static.dir/src/util/vector.c.i
.PHONY : src/util/vector.c.i

src/util/vector.s: src/util/vector.c.s

.PHONY : src/util/vector.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
src/util/vector.c.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/cli.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cli.dir/src/util/vector.c.s
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/plctag_dyn.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/plctag_dyn.dir/src/util/vector.c.s
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/plctag_static.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/plctag_static.dir/src/util/vector.c.s
.PHONY : src/util/vector.c.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... install/strip"
    @echo "... install"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... ab_server"
    @echo "... write_string"
    @echo "... thread_stress"
    @echo "... cli"
    @echo "... test_special"
    @echo "... simple_dual"
    @echo "... multithread_plc5"
    @echo "... multithread_plc5_dhp"
    @echo "... test_callback_ex"
    @echo "... simple_cpp"
    @echo "... list_tags_logix"
    @echo "... tag_rw"
    @echo "... busy_test"
    @echo "... barcode_test"
    @echo "... test_callback"
    @echo "... multithread_cached_read"
    @echo "... async_stress"
    @echo "... data_dumper"
    @echo "... plctag_dyn"
    @echo "... test_string"
    @echo "... async"
    @echo "... toggle_bit"
    @echo "... slc500"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... test_connection_group"
    @echo "... plctag_static"
    @echo "... plc5"
    @echo "... list_install_components"
    @echo "... simple"
    @echo "... install/local"
    @echo "... test_raw_cip"
    @echo "... stress_test"
    @echo "... toggle_bool"
    @echo "... list_tags_micro8x0"
    @echo "... string_non_standard_udt"
    @echo "... string_standard"
    @echo "... test_auto_sync"
    @echo "... tag_rw2"
    @echo "... test_tag_attributes"
    @echo "... test_many_tag_perf"
    @echo "... test_reconnect"
    @echo "... multithread"
    @echo "... stress_api_lock"
    @echo "... test_shutdown"
    @echo "... src/contrib/cli/cli.o"
    @echo "... src/contrib/cli/cli.i"
    @echo "... src/contrib/cli/cli.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/async.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/async.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/async.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/async_stress.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/async_stress.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/async_stress.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/barcode_test.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/barcode_test.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/barcode_test.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/busy_test.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/busy_test.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/busy_test.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/data_dumper.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/data_dumper.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/data_dumper.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/list_tags_logix.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/list_tags_logix.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/list_tags_logix.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/list_tags_micro8x0.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/list_tags_micro8x0.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/list_tags_micro8x0.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_cached_read.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_cached_read.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_cached_read.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_plc5.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_plc5.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_plc5.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_plc5_dhp.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_plc5_dhp.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/multithread_plc5_dhp.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/plc5.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/plc5.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/plc5.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple_cpp.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple_cpp.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple_cpp.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple_dual.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple_dual.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/simple_dual.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/slc500.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/slc500.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/slc500.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/stress_api_lock.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/stress_api_lock.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/stress_api_lock.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/stress_test.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/stress_test.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/stress_test.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/string_non_standard_udt.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/string_non_standard_udt.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/string_non_standard_udt.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/string_standard.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/string_standard.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/string_standard.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/tag_rw.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/tag_rw.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/tag_rw.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/tag_rw2.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/tag_rw2.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/tag_rw2.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_auto_sync.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_auto_sync.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_auto_sync.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_callback.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_callback.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_callback.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_callback_ex.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_callback_ex.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_callback_ex.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_connection_group.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_connection_group.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_connection_group.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_many_tag_perf.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_many_tag_perf.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_many_tag_perf.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_raw_cip.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_raw_cip.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_raw_cip.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_reconnect.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_reconnect.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_reconnect.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_shutdown.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_shutdown.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_shutdown.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_special.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_special.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_special.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_string.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_string.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_string.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_tag_attributes.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_tag_attributes.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/test_tag_attributes.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/thread_stress.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/thread_stress.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/thread_stress.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/toggle_bit.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/toggle_bit.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/toggle_bit.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/toggle_bool.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/toggle_bool.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/toggle_bool.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/utils_posix.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/utils_posix.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/utils_posix.s"
    @echo "... src/examples/write_string.o"
    @echo "... src/examples/write_string.i"
    @echo "... src/examples/write_string.s"
    @echo "... src/lib/init.o"
    @echo "... src/lib/init.i"
    @echo "... src/lib/init.s"
    @echo "... src/lib/lib.o"
    @echo "... src/lib/lib.i"
    @echo "... src/lib/lib.s"
    @echo "... src/lib/version.o"
    @echo "... src/lib/version.i"
    @echo "... src/lib/version.s"
    @echo "... src/platform/posix/platform.o"
    @echo "... src/platform/posix/platform.i"
    @echo "... src/platform/posix/platform.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/ab_common.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/ab_common.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/ab_common.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/cip.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/cip.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/cip.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_cip.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_cip.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_cip.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_cip_special.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_cip_special.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_cip_special.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_lgx_pccc.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_lgx_pccc.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_lgx_pccc.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_plc5_dhp.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_plc5_dhp.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_plc5_dhp.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_plc5_pccc.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_plc5_pccc.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_plc5_pccc.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_slc_dhp.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_slc_dhp.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_slc_dhp.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_slc_pccc.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_slc_pccc.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/eip_slc_pccc.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/error_codes.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/error_codes.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/error_codes.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/pccc.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/pccc.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/pccc.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/session.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/session.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/ab/session.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/mb/modbus.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/mb/modbus.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/mb/modbus.s"
    @echo "... src/protocols/system/system.o"
    @echo "... src/protocols/system/system.i"
    @echo "... src/protocols/system/system.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/cip.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/cip.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/cip.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/cpf.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/cpf.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/cpf.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/eip.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/eip.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/eip.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/main.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/main.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/main.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/pccc.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/pccc.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/pccc.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/socket.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/socket.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/socket.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/tcp_server.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/tcp_server.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/tcp_server.s"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/utils.o"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/utils.i"
    @echo "... src/tests/ab_server/src/utils.s"
    @echo "... src/util/atomic_int.o"
    @echo "... src/util/atomic_int.i"
    @echo "... src/util/atomic_int.s"
    @echo "... src/util/attr.o"
    @echo "... src/util/attr.i"
    @echo "... src/util/attr.s"
    @echo "... src/util/debug.o"
    @echo "... src/util/debug.i"
    @echo "... src/util/debug.s"
    @echo "... src/util/hash.o"
    @echo "... src/util/hash.i"
    @echo "... src/util/hash.s"
    @echo "... src/util/hashtable.o"
    @echo "... src/util/hashtable.i"
    @echo "... src/util/hashtable.s"
    @echo "... src/util/rc.o"
    @echo "... src/util/rc.i"
    @echo "... src/util/rc.s"
    @echo "... src/util/vector.o"
    @echo "... src/util/vector.i"
    @echo "... src/util/vector.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: The is a `cmake` generated `makefile`. You'd rather edit the `cmake` file instead.

Comment: @alex01011 I added the cmake_install.cmake file. Should I see the gcc command there?

Comment: Check for a `CMakeLists.txt` file.